# Extract only first level paragraphs from html

Tags: php

I have the following html:

```
<div id="myID">
  <p>I want this</p>
  <p>and I want this</p>
  <div>
    <p>I don't want this</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to extract only the first level `<p>...</p>` elements.

I've tried using the excellent `simple_html_dom` library e.g. `$html->find('#myID p')` but in the case above, this finds all three `<p>...</p>` elements

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Try using the `children` method (if that object has such method) or `>` in your selector: `$html->find('#myID > p')`

Comment: That still returns all paragraphs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of having to use some external library why don't you just use the built in classes to handle the dom?

First create a [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) instance using your HTML:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHtml($yourHtml);
```

After that use [DOMXPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) to select your elements:

```
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$nodes = $xpath->query("//*[@id='myID']/p");

var_dump($nodes->length); // outputs 2
```

This selects all `p` elements which are direct children of the element with the id `myID`. [Demo](https://eval.in/380957)