# BeautifulSoup extract top-level tags only

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm doing some web-scraping with BeautifulSoup in Python 3.4.

Now I have encountered a problem during my learning: 
I'm trying to get a table rows from a webpage and I'm using find_all() to get them, but inside the table - there are more table with table rows inside of them! how can I get *only* the top-level/first-level general or specific elements of a tag in BeautifulSoup?

```
# Retrieves all the row ('tr') tags in table
my_table.find_all('tr')
```

By the way, this question is a duplicate of this question (only the programming language used over there is PHP): [Extract only first level paragraphs from html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30816584/extract-only-first-level-paragraphs-from-html)

Answer (score 31):

Apparently there is an argument called *recursive* in the method *find_all()* and it is set by default to *True*.

Setting it to false, making the method to return only the top-level elements.

```
find_all('tr', recursive=False)
```